# Grid element on ul child

Tags: html, css, dom, grid

New to css, html and can't determine why the nav.grid element is not applying?  In the below codepen my question is why the ul {list-style-type:  none;} property does not apply?  Posted html, css and codepen below.  I am trying to create a nav bar using grid but cannot get the grid to apply.  I was using this https://coder-coder.com/responsive-navigation-bar-flexbox-vs-css-grid/ tutorial as a guide but modifying it slightly.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
            <nav class="nav.grid">
                <ul>
                    <li class="fullwidth"><a href="https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=EN"> Images </a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/advanced_search?"> Advanced </a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    <div>
        <div class="center">
                <div>
                    <form action="https://google.com/search">
                <input type="text" name="q">
                <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
            </form>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

html {
    font-size: small;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}

nav {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    @media (min-width: 600px){
        padding: 20px;
    }
    ul {
            list-style-type:  none;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
      }
    a {
      font-size: 1.25rem;
      
      @media (min-width: 42em){
        font-size: 2rem;
      }
    }
}

a::before {
}

a:hover {
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
}

nav.grid {
    ul {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
        grid-gap: 10px;
        justify-content: center;
        justify-items: center;

        @media (min-width: 600px){
            grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(3, fit-content(50px));
            grid-gap: 20px;
            justify-items: end;
        }
    }

    .fullwidth {
        grid-column: 1 / 4;
        @media (min-width: 600px){
            grid-column: 1 / 2;
            justify-self: start;
        }
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/dmwcode/pen/ExyWvGR

Comment: Can you add link to that tutorial page?

Comment: I added the link to the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's "Less" css code.
A browser does not understand Sass/Less code. Therefore, you will need a Sass/Less pre-processor to convert Sass/Less code into standard CSS.

This process is called transpiling. So, you need to give a transpiler (some kind of program) some Sass code and then get some CSS code back.

if you need standard css code Here you are :
Less to standard Css Converted of your code

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap"); html {
    font-size: small;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

nav {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    nav {
        padding: 20px;
    }
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav a {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

@media (min-width: 42em) {
    nav a {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}

a::before {
}

a:hover {
}

.center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 200px;
}

nav.grid ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    nav.grid ul {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(3, fit-content(50px));
        grid-gap: 20px;
        justify-items: end;
    }
}

nav.grid .fullwidth {
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    nav.grid .fullwidth {
        grid-column: 1 / 2;
        justify-self: start;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly the piece I was missing.  I was able to transpile the scss code to css and it worked as expected.  Your standard  css code was also helpful.  Thanks.